# How to change "Navigate backward" in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Default shortcut (Ctrl + .) is not working, I would like to change it to Mouse Button 4/5.

[image: Navigate backward button in Visual Studio 2013]

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut for navigating backward is `Ctrl` + `-`. Have you tried that?

You can also refer to [Customizing a keyboard shortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx#bkmk_assign)

Comment: Customizing keyboard shortcut is exactly what I looked for.